# Wrong Custom error message in server side validation for MVC6 TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In the MVC6 TagHelper i have created two text box and binded model for that with custom error message one textbox of type string and other of type int during the post back the custom error message specified in the data annotation is not rendered properly for type other than string.

My Controller is

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Sample model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The Model class is

```
public class Sample
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "String value is needed")]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Int value is needed")]
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

}
```

And My Html Tag Helper code is

```
@model ValidationMessage.Models.Sample
<form method="post" action="/Home/Index">
    <label>String</label>
    <input asp-for="StringValue" type="text" />
    <span asp-validation-for="StringValue"></span>
    <br />

    <label>Int</label>
    <input asp-for="IntValue" type="text" />
    <span asp-validation-for="IntValue"></span>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here am checking the server side validation alone, If i click the submit button
the first text box span validation shows **String value is needed** but the second text box span validation shows **The value '' is invalid.** instead of **Int value is needed**

Can someone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Make IntValue int?. And remove type="text" from the input.
That should do the trick.

Comment: Removing type="text" also results the same, IntValue is name of my property its already of type int.

Comment: make it a nullable int => int?

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you @KoenS

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without making it as nullable, because in MVC5 its working fine for MVC6 only its showing like this.